# spring manually add beans

Tags: java, spring

I have project using java 1.4 and spring 2.5.
It uses some 3rd party library, which provides some services.

```
class XFactory {
    Object getService(String name);
}
```

where `name` is name of interface of service, and method returns implementation.
I want to extend this class and register results as spring beans:

```
class YFactory extends XFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

     private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

     public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws       BeansException {
          this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
     }

     Object getService(String name) {
          Object service = super.getService(name);
          registerBean(applicationContext, name, service);
          return service;
     }

 }
```

How to implement `registerBean`?
I was googling but nth was working : casting appCtx to DefaultListableBeanFactory causes CCE, I cant change XFactory to FactoryBean (3rd party)

Answer (score 1):

'casting appCtx to DefaultListableBeanFactory causes CCE'
Get AutowireCapableBeanFactory by appCtx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory() and then cast it to BeanDefinitionRegistry.

Comment: Added sth like :


    `ConfigurableBeanFactory cfb =(ConfigurableBeanFactory)applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFatory();`
    `if(!cfb.containsBean(service.getName())) {`
        `cfb.registerSingleton(intfName, service);`
    `}`

Not sure if it is OK, but problably works - appCtx.getBean(name) returns sth != null, not fully tested yet.

And now I have other problem. I use Spring AOP, is it possible to proxy original service so it contains all aspects already defined in my aop.xml?

Comment: 'Not sure if it is OK' Your code is already dependent on Spring API directly, so if any changes to Spring in future may break that part(which is not likely). This move will not make big difference. For aop, I looked at code and unable to find answer.